# Apache and OS Yosemite

Tags: macos, apache, development-environment, osx-yosemite

I have just installed Yosemite (moved up from Mountain Lion) and, like many on here, it made my dev environment stop working. 
Having gone through the configuration process again I still find it is not working. In fact I can not even get the "It Works!" text showing when I enter localhost, and other path variations, in the url. 
Terminal says that Apache "Operation already in progress" but after starting, stopping, restarting over and over, I am stuck.

Comment: Are you using the default apache, Homebrew, or Macports?

Comment: Try this [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602475#26885389](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602475#26885389)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, by using migration assistant to set up the new mac (yosemite with apache2.4). In the new mac apache2 did not work, while in the old one worked. After some time, I noticed that in the file

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

the following module was commented

LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Just uncomment and hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to uncomment the following line in `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

Then restart Apache2.

Comment: I've just done a second shift using Apple's Migration Assistant (from a MacPro to a 5k Retina iMac) and again both virtual hosts and userdir would only load the default webserver "It works!" file.
This time I found `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf` in httpd.conf was commented out (where all my virtual hosts are set). Uncommenting this and restarting Apache had everything working correctly again.